# Console log outputting the entire function instead of what's being returned

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript and decided to make a Rock-Paper-Scissors game with the limited knowledge I've gained so far. However, I cannot figure out why it outputs

```
I chose function (userChoice)
    {
        if(userChoice==="Rock")
            return "Paper";

        if(userChoice==="Paper")
            return "Scissors";

        if(userChoice==="Scissors")
            return "Rock";
    }. I win noob.
```

rather than just "I chose Rock. I win noob."

Here's my code:

```
var main = function()
{
    var yesno = confirm("Would you like to play Rock-Paper-Scissors?");

    if(yesno === false)
        return "You're lame.";

    var userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

    var cheat = function(userChoice)
    {
        if(userChoice==="Rock")
            return "Paper";

        if(userChoice==="Paper")
            return "Scissors";

        if(userChoice==="Scissors")
            return "Rock";
    };

    return "I chose " + cheat + ". I win noob.";
};

console.log(main());
```

I found that it works by moving the `cheat` function outside and above the `main` function and adjusting some things, the code works as intended. I just cannot figure out why one method works while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `()`:

```
return "I chose " + cheat(userChoice) + ". I win noob.";
```

With the parentheses, JavaScript will insert the function in the string instead of calling it and inserting the result.

Comment: still not right... not passing in the argument. `cheat(userChoice)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm kind of embarrassed I missed something so simple and obvious haha.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `cheat` as a function -

```
return "I chose " + cheat(userChoice) + ". I win noob.";
```

You have to pass in `userChoice` again, since the `function(userChoice)` call is asking for a variable, and calling it `userChoice`. It is not, however, actually using the previously established `userChoice` variable.